# ¿Como eliminar guiones de una cadena de texto en PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo una duda,

> ¿como puedo eliminar los guiones `-` de una cadena de texto ?

Realicé lo siguiente pero no me funciona.

```
$cadena = "Mi-cadena-con-guiones"; 
$cadena = preg_replace('[\s+]',"", $cadena);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para poder eliminar los guiones puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
str_replace("-","",$cadena);
```

Lo que hará es buscar los guiones de esa cadena y remplazarlos por lo que gustes, en el ejemplo lo dejé `""` que el resultado será esto:

```
Micadenaconespacios
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: No funciona con los guiones de dialogo que son un poco mas largos que los normales

Comment: Gracias!.........

Answer (score 2):

La forma común es usar [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$cadena = "Mi-cadena-con-guiones"; 
$str = str_replace("-", " ", $cadena);
echo $str;
```

pero otra opción es usar [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) e [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) :

```
$str = "Mi-cadena-con-guiones";
$arr = explode("-",$string);
$str = implode(" ",$arr);
echo $str;
```

ambas opciones daran como resultado:

```
  Mi cadena con guiones
```

---

Tu decides si quieres reemplazar los - por un espacio `" "` o un espacio vacío `""`.

Comment: Estoy dando opciones posibles, sin duda la opción para reemplazar es usar      str_replace. Agrega tu respuesta.